# How to enforce gherkin-lint in the karate project for API testing?

Tags: karate, lint, gherkin

I want to enforce gherkin-lint in the karate project for API testing? What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: if you explain what you mean by gherkin-lint that would help. no one has asked for something like this in 6 years, so the best option is to contribute code, it is open source

Comment: I was referring to https://github.com/vsiakka/gherkin-lint to enforce rules around feature files. I could not find any implementation example in the karate documentation. I am also yet to try this at my end.